# jQuery IF var = value or #id clicked

Tags: jquery, hash, if-statement, hyperlink

I have the .live aspect working now so if links are clicked, my function is executed, but I'm trying to figure out how include an option for a direct link to the content as well. Something like this:

```
$(showDiv).is('shipping-timeline')
or
$("#inm_if_hc_shipping_timeline").live('click', function() {
  [code to show and hide divs]            
});
```

showDiv contains the value that identifies the proper id, extracted from the URL.

My Question: How do I construct the IF statement to execute if either case is true?

Can anyone help? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

So I took the IF parts from Graydot's answer and applied it to my code and here is a more complete example of what it looks like now:

```
$("#inm_if_hc_faq").bind('click', function(e) {
    if(showDiv == 'faq') {
            // prevent default behavior
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#inm_if_hc_content_faq").show("slow");   
            $("#inm_if_hc_content_shipping_timeline").hide("fast");
    }

        });
```

The most important part I was missing was having the default behavior and an IF that overrides it... thanks Graydot!

Now when the link is clicked, the div shows like it should, but not when the URL is entered.

Example: http://myurl.com/thispage.html?show=faq

I didn't include the function that populates the variable showDiv here, but I have verified in the console that it contains 'faq' as it should.

Anyone see what I am still missing?

Thanks!

**FINAL UPDATE: SOLUTION**

I didn't understand it at first, but the solution proved to be rethinking my approach. I appreciate that someone could see through my ignorance and came up with a great solution.

Here's the working code example:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    var hval = location.hash.slice(1);

    if (hval == "faq") {
        $("#inm_if_hc_content_faq").show("slow");   
                    $("#inm_if_hc_content_shipping_timeline").hide("fast");
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

With this, the link can be as simple as **href="#faq"** or from another page **href="http://mydomain.com/mypage#faq"**. No need to parse the URL for a variable or to use the IF statement to tell the difference between the nav link or an outside link.

Hope this helps someone else, so then I won't have to feel so ignorant! ;)

Comment: Question is unclear!!! Please explain a little bit more clearly.

Comment: Sorry it can be more clear. Please post the html for the link you are using, and how you are planning to differ whether it is a live or link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hashtag, perhaps? By binding to the "hashchange" event instead of the "click" event, you should be able to get the results you want.

```
// run specific code based on the url hash
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    var hval = location.hash.slice(1);
    if (hval == "timeline") {
        // run whatever code or function you like
    }
});

// trigger it on page load
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

});

Now just make your clickable link look like

```
<a href="#timeline">click me</a>
```

and you have a clickable, bookmarkable JavaScript function. Whenever the URL hash changes, the hashchange event will be triggered instantly.

Comment: My question was probably not clear enough. I'm really just trying to figure out how to combine the two scenarios into an IF statement so my code exicutes if either case is true.

Comment: Why would a hashchange event not suit your needs?

Comment: I guess I just don't understand enough about it. When I search on hashchange, I see a lot of references to the jQuery Hashchange plugin. Is that what you are using? In taking a closer look at your answer, I see where it might be a better solution and it would work whether the link were on the same page or a different one, right?

Comment: Please ignore the depth of my ignorance I showed above. Your solution rules! So much less weight than what I was trying to do. Thanks for looking past my lack of understanding and giving me a better solution!

Answer (score 1):

Jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/xff82/

```
<body>
  <a href="#target_div">Toggle</a>
  <div id="target_div">Some content</div>
</body>
```

The script would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').bind('click', function(e){
      // check that target points to a id, rudimentary check
      var target = (/#\w+/).exec(this.href); // null if does not match
      if (target){
        // prevent default behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //jQuery toggle. show/hide div
        $(target[0]).toggle();
      }
    })
  });    
</script>
```